# Collision Detection rotated rectangle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I've been working on this game for the iPhone and I need to detect collisions between at ball (rectangle) and another rotated rectangle (sometimes rotated, sometimes no)
I'm currently using the method described [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/18522)

It kinda works, sometimes fails when it's a bit rotated.
The problem I have is that it's too slow.
By the time it detects and changes the angle, the ball is "too deep" inside the bat and as in the next check of collision, it detects as if it is still colliding and changes the angle again.

Is there any better way to detect the collisions? I wouldn't mind moving to chipmunk or box2d, but I don't know how to use em, and I don't need any real world or other physics, so if possible i'd prefer

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is use triangle collision detection. A rotated square could translate into 2 triangles.

How to accomplish this is to try 3 test -- points (a,b), (b,c), and (a,c). (a, b and c being the points on the triangle) and test if anything is in between those points